# can not boot osx from usb

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I try to boot osx from usb which has been made as boot disk due to my mac mini file system choas.
I press the button 'c'/'option' after mac running, but both cases do not trigger the menu that let me to choose boot from usb.

After the light on usb blinks 100~200 times, it stop. Then it continue to enter the procedure that recovery the file system then fail and auto shutdown.

Does anyone met the same problem? 
I am not sure if usb has problem or my mac's problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to wrong formatting of the USB - how was it created?

Anyway, when you start up a Mac holding down the Option key, the boot volume menu appears on the screen - this shows all bootable volumes on the screen, making it simple to boot from any volume in your Mac.